# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "balance" is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am building a bot that allow users to send commands to the bot for an in-game currency. I have installed all required modules for this project and it is able to run its start up message in the command prompt.

However, I have an issue where the bot does not respond to my commands when called in the discord server. This is the [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5uyx.png) that is shown in cmd prompt. I have looked up to similar issues but it did not help me in fixing this issue.

I am open for constructive feedback on how I can further improve my codes as I am still new to python.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random

os.chdir("D:\\Work\\Programming\\Sublime Text\\Projects")

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "bot!")

##Event portion
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello, the bot is ready.")


@client.command()   ##Account opening
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    with open("bank.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(users,f)

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return false
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 150
    with open("bank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():##Bank data
    with open("bank.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users

async def balance(ctx):##Balance portion
    await open_account(ctx,author) ##Open an account if it is not an existing user
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]

async def earn(ctx):##Earning portion
    await open_account(ctx,author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    earnings = randomrange(1000)
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]

    await ctx.send(f"You made {earnings} dollars")

    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings
    with open("bank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    ##Embeded portion
    em= discord.Embed(title =f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color =discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    await ctx.send(emded = em)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Will do, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You always have to put `@client.command` before doing `async def`, otherwise it will not recognize it as a command.

Comment: I see, okay I'll take note!

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of functions to make it simple.

`async def` when you want to use `await`

`def` if there is no `await`

Your commands must be async functions, it would look like this

```py
@client.command
async def test(ctx):
    #code
```

In your case you are missing `@client.command` in `balance` `earn` and myabe more.

Comment: So does that mean I need to remove await?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/) sync from Async

Comment: Will do, Thank you!